Character not importing from italic properly
What am I doing wrong?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{OldStandard-Math.otf}[,]
\DeclareSymbolFont{alphabets}{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{n}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{alphabets}{"66}

\begin{document}
    I am trying to replace the mathmode f only $f(x)=x$ but it's not italic.
        \[abcdef=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\]
\end{document}

Output:

I'd use Latin Modern Math.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\setmathfont{OldStandard-Math.otf}

\newfontface{\subf}{latinmodern-math.otf}[NFSSFamily=lmm]
\DeclareSymbolFont{subf}{TU}{lmm}{m}{n}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \Umathcode`f="0 \symsubf "1D453
}

\begin{document}

I am trying to replace the mathmode f only $f(x)=x$ but it's not italic.
\[
abcdef=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i
\]

\end{document}



As David mentioned his comment, it's not safe to use unicode math and the CMR family, but the below may helps you to get the required output:
\begin{filecontents}{\encodingdefault cmr.fd}
\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{m}{it}{
   <-> cmmi10
}{}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{OldStandard-Math.otf}[,]


\DeclareSymbolFont{alphabets}{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{alphabets}{"66}

\begin{document}

    I am trying to replace the mathmode f only $f(x)=x$ but it's not italic.
        \[abcdef=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\]
\end{document}

But again, I'm mentioning that, it's not advisable.

Understood, how would you do it? I am open to another way. I am not very good when it comes to font manipulation so I just use whatever I can make work.

@Masum Is my suggestion not working?

I was talking about the safety, yes it works.

This seems to be completely wrong. You are avoiding a warning by declaring the 127-character cmmi10 font to be \encodingdefault ie TU Unicode encoded so you will get incorrect characters with no warning at all. Worse, you write it to an external .fd file so may corrupt other documents that load this file if it isn't deleted.

@DavidCarlisle I agreed, and my sincere apologies... But the OP want to change the character f only, so only I've suggested, please excuse. Already I mentioned that it's not advisable

Yes but you could do that by telling  luatex to use an omx encoded font not by telling your example tire tex system that cmmi is a unicode font
